# Is there a reason why Jekyll does not watch changes on imported .less files?

Tags: less, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I use Jekyll with [`jekyll-less`](https://github.com/zroger/jekyll-less). I have a `main.less` and a `secondary.less` file. `main.less` goes like this:

```
 @import secondary.less
 ...
```

Changes in `main.less` are rendered immediately by `jekyll`, but changes in `secondary.less` need an extra build. Is there a reason for that?